# How to trim to URL in NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, replace, nsstring

I got my url in this way when I debug:

```
myURL   __NSCFString *  @"(\n    "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0003_white_cloud.png"\n)"  0x0a8a3510
```

I tried to replace `(\n` and `\n)` to `""` by method

```
tringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" (\n " withString:@""
```

Finally I got my url in this way

```
myURL   __NSCFString *  @"   "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0003_white_cloud.png"" 0x08c12540
```

but what I want is

```
myURL   __NSCFString *  @"http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0003_white_cloud.png"  0x08c12540
```

Are there any good way to help me to get the string that I want?

Comment: Are you assigning the result of `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` to the variable?

Comment: When you do your replace operations you're not replacing the `\"` characters that are present in the original, nor are you trimming the "whitespace" on either end.

Comment: BTW, unless you have a really good reason for doing otherwise, use `NSString` for the class name.

Comment: FWIW, it's possible my edit screwed up what the OP intended to show. I saw the formatting looked wrong, and I thought it was because of missing backslashes. But now I'm not sure if that's debugger output, or what. Sorry if I messed it up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should trim non-URL characters from the ends of a string, plus parentheses characters:

```
NSMutableCharacterSet* urlSet = [[NSMutableCharacterSet alloc] init];
urlSet = [urlSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet URLUserAllowedCharacterSet]];
urlSet = [urlSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet URLPasswordAllowedCharacterSet]];
urlSet = [urlSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
urlSet = [urlSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet URLPathAllowedCharacterSet]];
urlSet = [urlSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
urlSet = [urlSet formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
urlSet = [[urlSet invertedSet] mutableCopy];
[urlSet addCharactersInString:@"()"];

myURL = [myURL stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:urlSet];
```

You may need to do that after stripping "\n" if it is actually a backslash+n rather than a newline char.

Comment: Updated to also strip parentheses.  Let me know if it needs any other tweaks.